# AWS ECS persistent storage solution

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I have one container with Gitlab and i need it to have safe and better if external data volume. I though about EFS as the best one but, if my container will fail will the data be in EFS? And maybe there are better solutions then EFS. Main key is persitant and HA but not very expensive. Also will be thankful for any guides about mounting EFS.

Answer (score 0):

ECS is ideal for durable storage to be used with ECS. The container and file system are independent, if the container fails the data will be kept. I found a tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/tutorial-efs-volumes.html).

Comment: Okay i see, but for some reason when I'm mounting i cant see all the files from /var/opt, only some, checked permissions and they seem to be fine, size of /var/opt is few Gbs but in EFS its just 200 Kb. Im thinking what can be a problem. If you have any ideas thanks

Comment: Did you try following the tutorial? You should be mounting EFS somewhere like /mnt/efs/fs1 . Only your data files go on EFS, not the OS files.

Comment: let me explain the whole situation. I have GitLab and it stores data in /var/opt in a docker container. I mounted it to /var/opt to send data to EFS. Is it the right idea? feels like no. I checked the tutorial but I'm not sure if there is the exact same situation as mine. I just need to somehow make /var/opt backed up and saved somewhere in safe place

Comment: You should describe your problem fully in the question, rather than just asking how to implement the solution you have in mind. Can you not configure gitlab to store data in a folder of your choice?

Comment: I guess you mean to store all this data in another directory? It's the default one, and I'm not sure if I'm allowed to change it. Also, I'm obviously mounting it inside container. Maybe I should just mount it to /mnt/efs/... and create cron job to copy files from /var/opt to /mnt/efs.

Comment: Maybe you should just use an EC2 server. I don't really see a big advantage using a container here.